# creating controller actions for many to many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two controllers an EmployeesController and a TasksController. I already set up a many to many through association and I created a EmployeeTasksController to handle the relationship 
This is what I added to routes.rb

```
### ASSIGING EMPLOYEES TO TASKS ###
      resources :tasks do
      resources :employees, controller: 'employee_tasks'
      end
```

And then the controller:

```
    class EmployeeTasksController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @task=Task.find(params[:task_id])
        @employee=@task.employees.create(employee_params)
        if @employee.save
          render json: @employee, status: :created, employee: @employee
        else
          render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end

    end
def employee_params
      params.require(:employee).permit(:name,:email,:deleted_at)
    end
```

schema.rb has:

```
create_table "employee_tasks", id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.uuid "employee_id", null: false
    t.uuid "task_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["task_id"], name: "index_employee_tasks_on_task_id"
    t.index ["employee_id"], name: "index_employee_tasks_on_employee_id"
  end
```

I also have

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :employee_tasks
  has_many :tasks, through: :employee_tasks

end
class Task < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :employee_tasks
    has_many :employees, through: :employee_tasks

end
class EmployeeTask < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :task
end
```

Now my question is: Did I implement the create method properly? Should I be able to assign one or multiple users to a task?

Comment: Hi @RubyBox please share model associations and employee_params definition.

Comment: I just added them

Comment: associations are defined in model like Employee.rb and Task.rb. where you have defined has_many relations. Please add them as well.

Comment: I just added them

Comment: What is it exactly you want to accomplish? That will create a new user record. If you just want to assign an exisiting user to a task then you have completely missed the mark.

Answer (score 0):

@RubyBox if you have following association in your models.

`Task.rb`

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employee_tasks
  has_many :employees, through: :employee_tasks
end
```

and in `EmployeeTask.rb` as follows,

```
class EmployeeTask < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

`Employee.rb`

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employee_tasks
  has_many :tasks, through: :employee_tasks
end
```

By using this `create` method you will be able to assign a task to multiple employees only if that employee is not already there in your database.

Best way to do this is create employee_task object in this action.

```
def create
  @task  = Task.find(params[:task_id])
  @employee = Employee.find_or_create_by(employee_params)
  @employee_task = EmployeeTask.new(task: @task, employee: @employee)
  if  @employee_task.save
   #return employee or employee_task  
  else
    #return employee or employee_task
  end
end
```

Comment: I actually do. I already know I can. I'm just asking if my controller action is correct. Could you also provide the proper implementation of update and index? That would be great

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to assign a users to a task you can either just do as part of normal tasks create or update action:

```
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_checkboxes :user_ids, User.all, :id, :name %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

```
class TasksController
  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    # ...
  end

  def update
    if @task.update(task_params)
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end

  private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:user_ids, ...)
  end
end
```